# duplicate message processing in spring integration application in multiple tomcats

Tags: spring-integration

I have spring web/integration application. In order to run the long running processes in the background, I have used queue backed by MongoDbMessageStore and polls the queue every one second.

I tried to send the messages(1000 messages per instance) to the gateway from the same application running on two tomcat instances. I verified that messages processed by server 1, are not being processed by server 2 and vice versa. I saw the document stored in the mongo collection. It has UUID (message id) and _group_complete, but i am not able to conclude how does spring avoids  duplicate message processing if  the application running on multiple instances with a single momgodb instance.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because `MongoDbMessageStore` uses `findAndRemove` operation.

And that's an expected behaviour for distributed environment.

Would be worse if you'd say the opposite.

Comment: Thanks Artem for the prompt reply. So, should i not be worried about duplicate processing of the message in multiple tomcat instances? Is there any url you can share, that depicts the message processing occurs in spring integration(ensures that no duplicate message processing be it using jdbc/mongo or any store)

Comment: Read our Manual, please. But to be honest the `ACID` principle is out of SI scope. It's really a responsibility of DB. So, the question "if several processes can do something with the same DB record" is for them. Right, we should use DB correctly and we try to do that in the Framewrok. As you see here it is `findAndRemove` to avoid duplicate from different processes.